# Moving some tables to separate database, does it make sense?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance

Our situation is a bit untypical, I guess...

We had a stored procedure that was called very often from multiple application. As it was a heavy procedure, joining multiple big tables, we decided to make a cache for its results. So now the procedure first checks if there's a cached result - if yes, returns it, if no, calculates it (big SELECT, many JOINs) and puts into cache table for further use. Cache rows are marked as "to be refreshed" in triggers on source tables (so if the source data changes, we invalidate the cache connected with this data).

The CPU usage on server machine visibly dropped after the cache was introduced, however, the database grew rapidly. The cache tables are very big and take 1/3 of database space. There is an idea to put them into separate database (mostly to avoid backuping them). But I'm worried about performance, won't using data from other database decrease the speed of the query significantly?

Comment: you could put the cached portions of the database into a new database on a seperate server. if you are planning on doing this on the same server, I think you are going to get a performance reduction as you will now have multiple databases on the same server both "fighting" for CPU resources not forgetting I/O contention on the drives for writing and reading data/log files...

Comment: I know I'll have some performance reduction, my problem is how to estimate if it'll be minimal or significant.

Comment: in theory, it should be minimul if you are simply performing a SELECT * from a table in that new database. You might just run into issues when running the proc to populate this new database, and someone is trying to pull the data out of it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you keep the cached data for so long? If cached data from say more than a month ago is rarely used you could just delete it. It is then not backed up and only if needed again it needs to be recalculated.

This will ofcourse only work if old cached data is by and large no longer used.

Comment: I need it for long. I actually don't know how often each row is accessed, because that would require an extra update or insert to some stats table and this would make the procedure slower. I'll gladly accept an idea how to check the cache rows usage without any overhead. I can only see, using sys.dm_exec_query_stats
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text that cache branch in procedure is used more often than calculation branch. I'm aware that some rows may be less needed, but I don't know how to check which ones, unless adding "times used" and "last used" columns updated on trigger on SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Can you build your cache outside your db? If you can that would freeup 1/3 of your db space. Memcache or ehcache could help.